# Incorrectly Inferred Type in Generic Closure with Protocol Extension Constrained by Self

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, protocols, swift4

While trying to implement a function in Swift I ran into an issue where it seems that type inference broke on certain function parameters. Taking notes from other languages, I wanted to implement a function in Swift which takes two parameters: an object and a block which returns another object of the same type as the previous object. I started implementing it like so:

```
func prepare<T>(_ object: T?, with block: ((T?) -> T?)) -> T? {
    return block(object)
}
```

After attempting to use that inside of a `UITableViewController` class, I experienced an issue with the naming, as it seemed to be struggling with the segue function `prepare(for:sender:)`

I decided to just change the name to resolve this one (I'll save the above for another question):

```
func bootstrap<T>(_ object: T?, with block: ((T?) -> T?)) -> T? {
    return block(object)
}
```

This name will do for now. So I have a `bootstrap(_:with:)` function which takes an object and a closure, returning an object of the same type as the object argument. I can call this easily with certain objects, for example an `Int`:

```
bootstrap(1, with: { $0 + 1 })  // returns 2
```

This of course isn't what the function is there for, however. So I used it in its actual intended application, where I have a small `UIView`-derived class with a single member:

```
class ContactDetailHeaderView: UIView, Nibbable {
    var user: User?
}
```

This is fetched from a nib using the following protocol extension function on the `Nibbable` protocol:

```
extension Nibbable where Self: UIResponder {
    static func getRoot(withOwner owner: Any, options: [AnyHashable:Any]? = nil) -> Self? {
        return self.nib.instantiate(withOwner: owner, options: options).first as? Self
    }
}
```

With this, we can retrieve an object from `nib` (our `UINib`object for this class) and cast it as `Self` which in this case is `ContactDetailHeaderView`. Then, we can use our previously declared function to setup the object. We do this inside of a `UITableViewController`-derived class `ContactDetailTableViewController` which I will condense for the purpose of this question:

```
class ContactDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var user: User?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.backgroundView = bootstrap(ContactDetailHeaderView.getRoot(withOwner: self), with: { $0?.user = self.user })
    }
}
```

However, we get an error invoking this function:

```
Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'user'
```

This is unexpected. Our `getRoot(withOwner:options:)` function should return `Self` which is `ContactDetailHeaderView`, right?

Let's expand on the type inference by replacing the shorthand arguments with named parameters and explicitly defined types:

```
bootstrap(ContactDetailHeaderView.getRoot(withOwner: self),
    with: { (header: ContactDetailHeaderView?) -> ContactDetailHeaderView? in
        header?.user = self.user
    }
)
```

Surely there is no way that our object can be interpreted as `UIView` now? Well, we still get the same error:

```
Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'user'
```

Why does this happen? Even when I check the autocomplete in Xcode, the `header` argument here shows the `user` member as a valid accessible property. Using the `getRoot(withOwner:options:)` function elsewhere produces the expected result:

```
ContactDetailHederView.getRoot(withOwner: self)?.user = self.user
```

Then why does it not work inside the `bootstrap(_:with:)` closure? Is this a bug? Is there something else I'm missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'll attach a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mtfourre/d20f20a397832b7d3401a53f9f7b4149) with enough code to reproduce the problem in a playground. For simplicity's sake, I'll replace some of the unnecessary bits with something more manageable (e.g. change `user` type from `User` which is an internal object to `String` which is available in the standard library)

Please keep in mind that this question is *not* about what the function does or why it does it. There are plenty of ways to implement the same thing, many of which are likely far better. I would like to solve this compiler error regardless of whether or not I even use this function in its current form.

Comment: Well the compiler seems to think that self is a pure `UIView` subclass. Unless i misread, you don't specify what class self refers to in your second-to-last code snippet. What is `self`, and is a user parameter present in the class which houses the `bootstrap` method? Might seem like a silly question, but you have both `header` and `ContactDetailHeaderView` class and the unknown `self` pointer claiming a user parameter. the first of the two does, so i'm betting you might have overlooked something with whatever self points to..

Comment: Right, I should include the context here. Let me edit the question @murphguy

Comment: No worries, looking over your gist now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please keep in mind that this question is not about what the function does or why it does it. There are plenty of ways to implement the same thing, many of which are likely far better. I would like to solve this compiler error regardless of whether or not I even use this function in its current form.

Good, because this has way too many optionals. But it's easy to fix (it's just really hard to understand because it's too complicated).

`bootstrap` is supposed to return a `T?`. You pass it this:

```
{ (header: ContactDetailHeaderView?) -> ContactDetailHeaderView? in
    header?.user = self.user
}
```

That returns `Void`. That causes the type engine to run down all kinds of rabbit holes (especially since any `T` can become `T?`). The fix is to return `T`:

```
{ (header: ContactDetailHeaderView?) -> ContactDetailHeaderView? in
    header?.user = self.user
    return header
}
```

In your gist, this would be:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = bootstrap(ContactDetailHeaderView.getRoot(withOwner: self), 
                                with: { $0?.user = self.user; return $0 })
```

Comment: The inner closure isn't actually supposed to return `T?`. It should be `Void`. My fingers were moving too fast for my brain.